# Why do some materials have negative Seebeck coefficients?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, thermoelectricity

I was looking in particular at Constantan with platinum when I was wondering how could something have a negative Seebeck coefficient.

I presumed that it must be linked to hole movement throughout the metal as opposed to electron movement but now I am wondering whether, with any pair of different metals, one would always have a positive Seebeck coefficient with regards to the second whilst the second would have a negative Seebeck coefficient with regards to the first. Would this be the case?

Comment: "Seebeck coefficient is X" is meaningless. Measurement always involves a pair of different metals.

Comment: @Pieter Oh yes sorry, I meant relative to platinum for the example with constantan. However, I am struggling to see why it would ever be negative, regardless of any pairings of metals.

Comment: For any pair of metals, if there is an effect for A relative to B, the Seebeck coefficient is negative to B with respect to A. So if you understand the positive effect, you understand the negative sign too.

Comment: @Pieter, so are you saying that in any thermocouples, one of the metals is positive with respect to other and the other is negative with respect to the first? So there is nothing to do with movement of holes or the like?

Comment: A simple explanation works when the charge carrier density is so low that the material can be regarded as a classical gas of electrons or holes. This is the case in relatively lightly doped semiconductors. The Seebeck coefficient is large then. For a Fermi gas, the effect is orders of magnitude smaller, requires different theory.

Comment: @Pieter, thank you for your help,  I would just like to clarify something with you. Say there were two metals,  A and B.  Would it be possible for A to have a Seebeck coefficient of  say 1 V/K measures relative to B and B to have a Seebeck coefficient of 2 V/K relative to A  or would one have to be negative (as in B is - 2 V/K )?

Comment: could you update your question to reflect anything you've learned in this discussion?

Comment: I do not really agree with Pieter's comment that a Seebeck coefficient of X is meaningless. One can get the absolute Seebeck coefficient via several different ways, such as using a superconductor or by measuring the Thomson coefficient (no need for 2 materials in that case, a single material is enough).